# I am trying to generate a pdf document from python.I am expecting it to print only once in output file but it is printing it four times

Tags: python, django, pdf, report

1. This script tries to generate pdf file.
2. it use python's pollyreport library.

   ```
   from PollyReports import *
   from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
       output = []
       with open('textfile.txt','r') as f:
           for line in f:
               if 'india' in line:
                   output.append(line)
   print output
   rpt = Report(datasource = output, detailband = Band
               ([
                   Element((10,10), ("Helvetica", 12), text=output[0]),
               ]))        

   canvas = Canvas("lprep01.pdf")
   rpt.generate(canvas)
   canvas.save()
   ```